# using JNI AndroidJNI.GetMethodID in unity with string parameters

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, java-native-interface

I'm working on unity with android java plugin I was trying to call function from java in unity and it worked successfully.

```
        cls_Activity = AndroidJNI.FindClass("com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer");
        fid_Activity = AndroidJNI.GetStaticFieldID(cls_Activity, "currentActivity", "Landroid/app/Activity;");

        obj_Activity = AndroidJNI.GetStaticObjectField(cls_Activity, fid_Activity);
        kdataActivityClass = AndroidJNI.FindClass("com/kdata/unitytest/UnityUrlPlugin");
startAdsMethod = AndroidJNI.GetMethodID(kdataActivityClass,"getURL","(I)Ljava/lang/String;");

        jvalue[] myArray = new jvalue[1];
        myArray[0].i =testvalue;
        gui.text=   AndroidJNI.CallStaticStringMethod(obj_Activity, startAdsMethod, myArray);
```

Using above code, I was enable to pass `int` value to my java function and recieve `string` value . When I'm trying to pass a string value, it's not working for me. The problem is somewhere here because there is no string type in JNI

```
jvalue[] myArray = new jvalue[1];
myArray[0].i =testvalue;
```

Comment: have you tried jstring? Your question isnt very clear, and there are parts of your code missing

Comment: i solved it brother 
and this is what i wanted 
myArray[0].l = AndroidJNI.NewStringUTF(credentials);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved it brother and this is what i wanted myArray[0].l=AndroidJNI.NewStringUTF(credentials);

Answer (score 2):

The data type you are looking for is jstring and in JNI you can create it using `newString` or `newStringUTF`

Answer (score 0):

> there is no string type in JNI

Yes there is. It's called 'jstring'.

Comment: The problem is that he's using Unity, and for some reason they expose jvalue but not jstring.